# Why is a multiple parent exception not caught?

Tags: python, exception

I toyed around with an exception hierarchy and realized that
an exception subclass with several parents is not caught.

For example:

```
class Error1(Exception): 
    pass

class Error2(Exception): 
    pass

class MixedError(Error1, Error2): 
    pass

try:
    print('before 1')
    raise Error2()
    print('after 1')

except MixedError:
    print('Caught it with a mixin 1!')

except Exception:
    print('Big catcher here 1!')
```

This prints:

> before 1
>
> Big catcher here 1!

**Why is a multiple parent exception not caught?**

Comment: The `raise Error2()` is caught by the `except Exception:` block.  What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: Why should it? `MixedError` is an inheritor of `Error2`.

Comment: Yes but exceptions are cached by _parent_ exception, not by _child_ exceptions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a misunderstanding how `exceptions` work. Exceptions are caught by parent exceptions, not by child exceptions:

```
class Error1(Exception):
    pass

class Error2(Exception):
    pass

class MixedError(Error1, Error2):
    pass

try:
    print('before 1')
    raise MixedError()
    print('after 1')

except Error2:
    print('Caught it with a Error2!')

except Exception:
    print('Big catcher here 1!')
```

prints:

```
before 1
Caught it with a Error2!
```

Answer (score 1):

You never raise `MixedError`. Also, note that parent classes know nothing about child classes, thus, when raising `Error1` or `Error2`, you are raising an error using the `__str__` from that specific class:

```
class Error1(Exception): 
   pass

class Error2(Exception): 
   pass

class MixedError(Error1, Error2): 
   pass

try:
   raise MixedError('Error here')
except MixedError:
   print("caught 'MixedError'")
```

Output:

```
caught 'MixedError'
```